react-native-webrtc build with preview profile crashes
I'm having a problem with react-native-webrtc:
My eas build in profile development works completely, but my builds in preview crash as soon as they open.
The eas.json has the default content.
I don't understand what justifies the difference in results between the two build profiles, so I don't have any clues on how to solve the problem. If anyone has any ideas to help me, I'd be grateful.
I've tried checking my package.json and metro.config.js, but nothing works. Here they are:
package.json:
{
  "config-plugins/react-native-webrtc": "^9.0.0",
  "@expo/metro-config": "^0.18.11",
  "expo": "~51.0.38",
  "react-native": "0.74.5",
  "react-native-webrtc": "^124.0.4"
}

metro.config.js:
Copier le code
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const resolveFrom = require("resolve-from");

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
config.resolver.extraNodeModules = {
  "event-target-shim": require.resolve("event-target-shim")
};

config.resolver.resolveRequest = (context, moduleName, platform) => {
  if (moduleName.startsWith("event-target-shim") && context.originModulePath.includes("react-native-webrtc")) {
    const eventTargetShimPath = resolveFrom(context.originModulePath, moduleName);
    return { filePath: eventTargetShimPath, type: "sourceFile" };
  }
  return context.resolveRequest(context, moduleName, platform);
};

config.resolver.assetExts = [...config.resolver.assetExts, 'db', 'sqlite'];
const { transformer, resolver } = config;

config.transformer = {
  ...transformer,
  babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
};

config.resolver = {
  ...resolver,
  assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
  sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"]
};

module.exports = config;

